# Get Kernel in Migration Symfony

Tags: php, symfony, console, migration

I want to run console app during migration.

```
$application = new Application($kernel);
    $application->setAutoExit(false);

    $input = new ArrayInput(array(
       'command' => 'app:data-insert',  
    ));

    $output = new NullOutput();
    $application->run($input, $output)
```

How can I get *KernelInterface* $kernel in migration file? Symfony 3.3

Comment: Why don't you look how `bin/console` looks like?

Comment: Just want to run *bin/console d:m:m* and execute *app:data-insert* as well. Without actual typing it. It can be tens of commands for updating data.

Comment: Why don't you run `bin/console app:data-insert` instead? I do not understand what problem you are solving. Please add some background information to your question to help us understand your problem.

Comment: There are a lot of console commands(apps) for updating data. I just want to write migration to combine them into one place. I can actually write bash file. But if it will be possible via migration, it'll be easier to support.

Comment: why don't you create a Makefile then ? You could execute all your commands with one alias

Comment: @Snroki I just want to keep all data manipulation in migrations. New member of team can just run migrations and have actual data, without dumping and running any scripts.

Comment: I still don't understand your question. Last try: Why don't you use `bin/console app:data-insert`? Where is your code snippet from your question coming from? In what file? What do you mean by 'a lot of console commands(apps) for updating data'? Have you looked at how `bin/console` works? Your question is unclear, please fix it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check: https://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/DoctrineMigrationsBundle/index.html#container-aware-migrations.

$this->container->get('kernel');

Personal opinion: You can do this, but you shouldn't. Data migration commands have a tendency to crash. In case of a crash, you could end up with a half-done migration, and possibly a bad state of database schema. Running the migrations again will not work because of the bad state.

If you do this, at least never mix schema and data migrations, but create 2 migrations. That way if the data migration fails, at least it won't try to do the schema changes on the 2nd run.

Comment: Thanks, I've forgot that we actually have a container. I just wanna try like new way. But your notices and others are really good. I will take it into consideration.